# What should I use the IDP identity provider token for

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, access-token, firebaseui

Bear with me please I try to understand the sing-in-flow in the [FirebaseUI](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android).
What is the differens between [IdpResponse](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-Android/blob/e14170d2006bdffc767f69b740e1dd7cbc3c79b5/auth/src/main/java/com/firebase/ui/auth/IdpResponse.java), `IdpResponse.getIdpToken()` and the `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid()` token?

I understand and use the later Firebase token as user identifier. What should I use the IDP identity provider token for?

Comment: The IDP token is the token from the identity provider, e.g. Twitter when your user signs in with Twitter. But this sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Please describe the problem you're trying to solve.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When going through the FirebaseUI sample app code I stumbled upon yet another token and asking her about how to use it. I did search for an A but it´s often so technical so I dont understand, so I askes this Q.